# how do i Zoom and pan an SVG Document embed in XHTML Page using AMPLE SDK

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, vector-graphics

Hello i am developing my map from raster to vector

i have managed to embed the SVG Map File into the XHTML page and i am using AMPLE SDK Library it is great works on all browsers.

but how can i use this library to zoom and pan into the map?
i am using AMPLE SDK because the Raphael Converter from SVG To Raphael not working in 
good way.
[RAPHAEL CONVERTER](http://toki-woki.net/p/SVG2RaphaelJS/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement zoom and pan on SVG fragment by manipulating viewBox attribute on svg element as echo-flow suggested. However you should be using setAttribute to get the change reflected:

```
ample.getElementById("mysvg").setAttribute("viewBox", "500 500 1000 1000");
```

or

```
ample.query("#mysvg").attr("viewBox", "500 500 1000 1000");
```

Study the format of viewBox attribute and it will not be difficult to find out how it should be manipulated.

Comment: thank you so much Sergey and echo-flow, also i have found this http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/OrganizationChart/Default.xhtml which helps me with the zoom and pan issue, but i have problem with IE the Javascript load is taking very long time, also the zoom and pan is deadly slow!!

Comment: Dear Sergey, i have problem with viewBox manipulation it is working fine on chrome,Firefox,Opera,Safari But not working on IE??? is this a bug is this bug related to this bug confirmation http://groups.google.com/group/amplesdk/browse_thread/thread/99d85bb17cb27f58/ecca240b25ba465e?lnk=gst&q=scaling#ecca240b25ba465e and how can i fix this bug in order to get it work on IE , IE Browser has wrong response for the ViewBox Changes instead of zooming the svg move to the right and bottom!!!, how would i fix this it is only IE problem, there is no problem in other browsers

Answer (score 0):

If Ample SDK supports dynamic SVG (and it looks like it does), then you can add this functionality by scripting the SVG root element's viewbox property in response to mouse events.  For example.

```
var newX = 100;
var svg = document.documentElement;
svg.viewBox.baseVal.x = newX;
```

You would still need to hook up this code to respond to mouse events.

If you want library support, you can look into using the jQuery SVG library (although, again, I'm not sure how well this will play with Ample): http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

A demo of jquery SVG being used to perform an animated zoom using viewbox can be found here: http://keith-wood.name/svg.html#anim